# Code to apply expression tree directly to List

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expression-trees

Is there a method call in Linq that will apply a expression tree directly on a `List<V>`? For instance, if I have a expression tree that is built on `Order` type, and i have a collection of `List<Order>` items on which i need to apply this expression.

I am looking something similar to:

```
class OrderListStore : IQueryable<V>,
    <other interfaces required to implement custom linq provider>
{
    List<Order> orders;

    public Expression Expression
    {
        get { return Expression.Constant(this); }
    }

    IEnumerator<V> IEnumerable<V>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        //Here I need to have a method that will take the existing expression
        //and directly apply on list
        something like this .. Expression.Translate(orders);
    }

}
```

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: also `Select` can be used like that

Comment: Very, very vague question.  Can you give a more specific example of what the `Expression` might be and what "apply" means here?  In your code, your "expression" is just a constant, so it's hard to see how you could "apply" a `this` expression to `orders` via some kind of `Translate` method.

Answer (score 2):

All of the interesting LINQ methods require a generic lambda expression - i.e. an `Expression<SomeFuncType>`, for example `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` for predicates (`where`), or `Expression<Func<TSource,TValue>>` for projections (`select`).

What you are doing *sounds* like `Select`, but you're going to have to give it a more specific lambda to be useful, and that doesn't work easily - you'd probably need a bit of `MakeGenericMethod` etc.

Re applying an `Expression` to LINQ-to-Objects, that is the easy bit. You can just use:

```
var projection = theList.AsQueryable().Select(lambda);
```

or

```
var filtered = theList.AsQueryable().Where(lambda);
```

(but note again that `lambda` there must be appropriately typed; `Expression` won't cut it).

(Alternatively, you can call `.Compile()` on the lambda and use regular LINQ-to-Objects)